React with NPM packages and using their minified version in the final webpack prod build
I have a React project which uses an NPM based library. When producing the production build of the app with webpack the library takes up a large portion of the final bundle size.
For the production bundle I would prefer not include that library in the bundle to reduce size, and instead use the minified version whether that is served up from a  include from a CDN or from a our local server, or perhaps some other way (webpack config?).
Is this even a valid thing that is possible and if so how would I go about that?
I am currently using Yarn V1.22 but am looking at V4.5 if that makes any difference. Also the use of webpack is not a hard requirement.
My attempts at Googling this have not led me to anything useful. I think I basically need the NPM package installed for dev purposes, but the prod build I want to use the minified version to reduce the bundle size.
Again this is assuming that what I'd like is valid.
